# how object properties convert to htmlentities

Tags: php

I created a query in mysql using PDO and I use FETCH_OBJ to return data as object,
I want to print it as JSON for Ajax call and I saw an example also here in stackoverflow and it's working.
Here is the code.

```
$post_datas // this is where the query results saved

echo json_encode( (array)$post_datas );
```

but myproblem is i want to make each properties convert to htmlentities because there is no htmlentities function in javascript. Is there a shortcut to make each properties convert to htmlemtities or I need to create a loop and set each properties to html properties before i do json_encode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a html entities in JavaScript it's called encodeURIComonent. Also no reason to fake cast the object as an array in the json_encode.

Also if you want to do that there is no predefined function. You will need to loop over the properties and just do html entities on each property

```
foreach($postDatas as $key => $val){
    $postDatas->$key = htmlentities($val);
}
```

Comment: thanks i wil look for encodeURIComonent. but what you mean in no reason to fake cast the object as an array? is there a way to json_encode the object or i need to convert first in array?

Comment: You can just json_encode the object. There is no reason to make it an array.

Comment: ah your right i try it and have the same result. thanks